# I cannot Configure two codeigniter installations on the same server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, staging

I'm trying to create a staging environment for my CI based webapp.

I have configured my main CI installation to work with Development and Production environments. Now I want to have a second CI installation on a sub-domain say `stage.mysite.com` which acts as an staging environment.

Ho do I configure my server or CI so that sub-domains work?

Comment: When you create a subdomain a folder will be created for you in your website root folder. Place another copy of your CI files there including index.php. That will work, if you want to share system folder you can do it by modifying in the index.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it wasn't CodeIgniter installation, it was a permission issue.

My Host throws `500` when group permission is set to writable.

After doing a `chmod 755` to the whole sub-domain directory the site started working normal.

This is wiered though.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/index.php` add the following around line 23

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
    case "stage.mysite.com":
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'stage');
    case "mysite.com":
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
    break;
    default:
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
    break;
}
```

Add this to your ERROR REPORTING section of index.php

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'stage':
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

In your `/application/config` directory, create subdirectories for your environments

```
/application/config/development/
/application/config/stage/
/application/config/production/
```

Copy the `config.php` file from `/application/config/` to the subdirectories and modify the `base_url` and `encryption_key` configs.

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://stage.mysite.com';`